# Суммирование значений в группах в Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, агрегация

Помогите,пожалуйста!
Есть DataFrame `df1` вида:

```
Значение1   -8.5     
Значение1   -12.1    
Значение2   -3.0     
Значение2   -5.0    
Значение3   -4.4
```

В итоге я хочу получить DataFrame `df2` вида:

```
Значение1   -20.6     
Значение2   -8    
Значение3   -4.4
```

Как просумировать повторяющиеся значения?
Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]:
        name   val
0  Значение1  -8.5
1  Значение1 -12.1
2  Значение2  -3.0
3  Значение2  -5.0
4  Значение3  -4.4

In [74]: df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['val'].sum()
Out[74]:
        name   val
0  Значение1 -20.6
1  Значение2  -8.0
2  Значение3  -4.4
```

Comment: MaxU, СПАСИБО тебе огромное !!!